# Show that $x f \cdot f'' + f \cdot f' - x (f')^2 > 0$ for certain $f(x) = 1 + x - c x^2 + x^3 + x^4$.

Tags: calculus

Consider the polynomial $f(x) = 1 + x - c x^2 + x^3 + x^4$ where $c \ge 0$. Suppose that $|f(z)| < f(|z|)$ for every complex number $z \notin [0, \infty)$. How can we show that $$F(x):= x f(x)\cdot f^{\prime\prime}(x) + f(x) \cdot f^\prime(x) - x (f^\prime(x))^2 > 0$$ for all $0\le x \le 1$?

Comment: Why not plug it into the inequality and check if it is true.

Comment: What is $t$ ? Do we have $t=c$ ? or $t=x$ ?

Comment: You want to know, for which $c$ the  inequality is valid ? Then put $f(x)$ into the  inequality as *MrYouMath* said. E.g. for $(x;c):=(1;5)$ it's not valid.

Comment: What are the domain and codomain of $f$?

Comment: Kelenner, sorry for the typo. $t$ should be $x$. I've made the change.

Comment: user90369, by plugging $z = - 1$ in the inequality $|f(z)|< f(|z|)$, we get $|-c| < 4 - c$ so that $c < 2$. So $(x ; c) = (1 ; 5)$ does not serve as a counterexample.

Comment: Rodrigo de Azevelo, $f$ is a polynomial with real coefficients. However, when interpreting the inequality $|f(z)| < f(|z|)$, we allow $z$ to take any complex value in the complement of $[0, \infty)$.

Comment: MrYouMath, a direct computation shows that $F(x) = 1 - 4 c x + (9 - c) x^2 + 20 x^3 + (9 - c) x^4 - 4 c x^5 + x^6$. However it is not clear why $F(x) > 0$ for $0 \le x \le 1$.

Comment: Experimenting shows that the inequality is true for $0\leq c<1.78194$, and false for larger $c$.

Comment: Christian Blatter, by plugging $z = (1 + 3 i)/ \sqrt{10}$ in the inequality $|f(z)|< f(|z|)$, we get $|-\frac{4}{25} + i \frac{3}{25}| \cdot |5 c - \sqrt{10} + 8| < 4 - c$ so that $c < \frac{6}{5} + \frac{\sqrt{10}}{10} \approx 1.516$ (using $c > 0$). So if indeed $F(x) > 0$ for $0 \le x \le 1$ whenever $0 \le c < 1.78194$, then we have a proof.

Comment: Making a substitution $y = x + \frac{1}{x}$, we have $F(x) = x^3 G(y)$ where $G(y) = (20 + 8 c) + (6 - c) y - 4cy^2 + y^3$. For $ c > \frac{18}{17}$, this cubic $G(y)$ has minimum value $-\frac{2}{27} (64 c^3+18 c^2+ \sqrt{(16 c^2+3 c-18)^3}-216 c-270) = : H(c)$. WolframAlpha says that $H(c) = 0 $ when $c = \frac{3}{43} (-2+8 \cdot 2^{1/3} +11 \cdot 2^{2/3}) \approx 1.78191488$.

Comment: So we can make an argument along this lines. The cubic $G(y)$ has minimum value $\min\{H(c), 40 - 10 c\}$. The function $H(c) > 0$ whenever $c < \frac{3}{43} (-2+8 \cdot 2^{1/3} +11 \cdot 2^{2/3}) \approx 1.78$. Since $c < 1.52 < 1.78 < 4$, so $H(c) > 0$ and $40 - 10 c > 0$. Thus $G(y) > 0$ for all $y$.

Answer (score 1):

The expression that should be positive for $0< x\leq1$ computes to
$$g(x,c):=1+9x^2 +20x^3+9x^4+x^6-cx(4+x+x^3+4x^4)\ .$$
We then can reformulate the question as follows: For which $c\geq0$ do we have
$$p(x):={1+9x^2 +20x^3+9x^4+x^6\over x(4+x+x^3+4x^4)}>c\qquad(0<x\leq1)\ ?$$
This amounts to finding the minimum of $p(x)$ in the given interval. The inherent symmetries of $p$ suggest putting
$$x+{1\over x}=: u\ ,\qquad{\rm resp.}\qquad x={1\over2}\bigl(u-\sqrt{u^2-4}\bigr)\qquad(u\geq2)\ .$$
After some calculations one finds that 
$$q(u):=p\bigl(x(u)\bigr)={u^3+6u+20\over 4u^2+u-8}\qquad(u\geq2)\ .$$
A plot of $q$ shows that $q$ is unimodal in the given range with a global minimum between $u=4$ and $u=5$. The minimum is found by solving $q'(u)=0$, which leads to the third degree equation $u^3-12u-34=0$. Fortunately the unique real solution $u_*$ can be expressed as
$$u_*=\tau+2\tau^2\doteq4.4372\ ,$$
with $\tau:=2^{1/3}$. The minimum of $q(u)$ for $u\geq2$, hence the minimum of $p(x)$ for $0<x\leq1$ is then given by
$$q(u_*)={6(2\tau^2+\tau+3)\over 2\tau^2+11\tau+8}\doteq1.78191\ .$$
It follows that the desired inequality holds when $0\leq c<q(u_*)$.